# How can I move files from current folder to previous folder?

Tags: bash

How can I move files from current folder to previous folder ?

for example, if I am in folder the contain file with name `f.txt` and I want to move it to the previous folder, how can I do it?

I tried something like that, but it's not working:

```
mov f.txt ./
```

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variable `OLDPWD` stores the last directory you were in before doing a `cd` to change the current directory.

Be sure to put double quotes around `"$OLDPWD"`, otherwise if the previous folder contained spaces in its path, e.g. `/home/me/some folder`, bash will split the path into two arguments, and `mv` will therefore try to move `f.txt` and `/home/me/some` into `folder`, which is not what you want of course.

```
$ pwd
/home/me/some folder
$ cd /tmp
$ mv f.txt "$OLDPWD"
$ ls "/home/me/some folder"
… f.txt …
```

If instead you want to move the file to the parent folder, then the following will work:

```
$ mv f.txt ..
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough:

```
mv * ..
```

If you need something specific, for example, if you know the extension of the files (for example for text files, you can use `*.txt`):

```
mv *.txt ..
```